# Jmeter throwing service unavailable error when using jks in ssl manager

Tags: jmeter

I converted mycert.cer file to mycert.jks using keytool (from jdk) and I am using it in SSL manager in JMeter. Set implementation to Java. When I run my script, it pop up for JKS password (enter password for jks which was set during conversion), then the result it shows as "Application is not available" (response code - 503). But I can see that there is no issue with the application or endpoint as it is working in Load Runner and postman.
Here for help, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot help without seeing:

1. The command you're using for adding the certificate to the keystore
2. Configuration of LoadRunner or Postman and JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
3. [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

You can also try setting the path to the keystore and password using `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` properties, it will protect you from making a typo during keystore import and will enable test execution in command-line non-GUI mode. See [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) for more details

And last but not the least, you don't need to switch HTTP Request sampler's implementation to "Java", client certificates are normally supported with HTTPClient4, moreover you will be able to use multiple certificates with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dmitri. I checked the log and found ERROR o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Problem loading keystore: No key(s) found
java.io.IOException: No key(s) found. I also checked that the application unavailable error is only coming when I change implementation to Java and it is not related to SSL. In Load Runner too I faced this issue. But, using Web_set_cert function along with argument certIndex=1" and using WinInet solved the issue. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I also tried adding https.keyStoreStartIndex=1 and https.keyStoreEndIndex=1. Enabled javax.net.debug=ssl. All I see in the console is " no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication"